# How to attach javadoc to Google Play Services in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

Reference documentation for `com.google.android.gms:play-services` can be found at `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference` but I can't figure out how to attach it in Android Studio.

Android Studio 0.8.4, Gradle Android Plugin 0.12.2

Comment: I'm not sure the docs in the path you reference are on JavaDoc format. I tried attaching them by zipping the folder, naming it by convention and using the aarLinkSources* plugin to Gradle, but it didn't work. *) https://github.com/xujiaao/AARLinkSources

Comment: ..and Google needs to get their act together and release the javadoc in a standardized way with the maven repo provided by the SDK manager.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Android Studio 1.5.1 this is how I've managed to add the javadocs:

1. Right click in **Project panel**  > **External libraries** > **lib-name**
2. Click **Library properties**
   [image: Lib props]
3. Click specify documentation URL
4. And specify an URL. For my machine it was `file:///opt/android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference`
   [image: Add doc url]
5. The result was:
   [image: added jdoc]
6. And after a project sync I could browse the javadoc of the **google play services**
   [image: google play services maps javadoc]

Answer (score -4):

A new version of the Google Play Services library was released recently: 5.2.08. If you are using an older version of the library, Android Studio will automatically offer to upgrade it to the new version. However, due to a bug, it drops the leading zero in "08", which means it replaces the dependency with "5.2.8" instead of "5.2.08" which does not work. To fix this, edit the dependency to read "5.2.08" instead of "5.2.8".

I got this information from [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74612) link.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if this has helped you?

Comment: How is this related to the question about the javadoc?

Comment: please answer the question